# Free theory in AdS/CFT

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft

In $AdS_5$/$CFT_4$, scalar fields of mass $m$ are mapped to conformal operators of dimension $\Delta$ via the dictionary:

$$\frac{m^2}{L^2} = \Delta(\Delta - 4)\tag{$*$}$$

From the string theory point of view one can realise $\mathcal{N}=4$ super Yang--Mills theory with gauge group $\mathrm{SU}(N)$ by considering type IIB on AdS$_5\times S^5$. The gauge coupling is then identified with the string coupling: $g_\text{YM}^2 = 4 \pi g_s$ and $N$ comes from stacks of $\mathrm{D}3$-branes.

To perform computations in the bulk, one needs to be in the supergravity limit, corresponding to the large $N$ limit on the CFT side. I am wondering what is the string description of the free SYM.

I have read that finding the string excitations in the limit $g_s\to0$ is a very hard problem. However for a free theory, the operators are just product of scalars of the form

$$\mathcal{O}_\text{free} \sim \text{Tr}(\phi^n)\,,\qquad \Delta = n\,,$$

where the dimension is just given by the number of field as there is no interactions. I would expect the mass associated to excitations of the n-th level of the string with $g_s$ to just have mass

$$\frac{\big(M^{(g_s=0)}_n\big)^2}{L^2} = n(n-4)\,?$$

While I could see that in principle finding deviation from $g_s = 0$ can be very hard because solving the worldsheet model will be complicated for that background, what is wrong with the last formula, i.e. at the free point? As far as I understand the dictionary ($*$) does not rely on string theory and is simply found by looking at the boundary of AdS.

Comment: Single trace operators are dual to closed string states. The large N limit is really dual to weakly interacting quantum strings on AdS_5.